# Is there any way to disable options of Select 2 which has larger values than the value of option selected in Select 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select in a form.
They are not siblings. They both has 15 options which has 1-15 values. And what I need to get is that when an option is selected from **Select A** which has a value of 5. Then the options of **Select B** which has larger value than 5 should be disabled.

This is my code:

```html
<select name="" id="children">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="child_going_school">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

So if the person selects 5 children, the school going children should not be greater than 5.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have disabled the same valued option from the Select 2. But cannot get all of them greater than the selected value.

Comment: Post your code :)

Comment: `$('#children').change(function() {
    
    var value = $(this).val();
 
    $('#child_going_school').children('option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
        }
    });
    
});`

Comment: @NomiRajput Post your code in the question rather in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($){
    $('#child_going_school').change(function() {

        var val1 = parseInt($('#children').val());
        var val2 = parseInt($(this).val());

        console.log(val1)
        console.log(val2)

        if(val1 != ''){
            if(val2 > val1){
                $(this).val(val1);
            }
        }

    });
});
```

In this if the second dropdown value is greater than first then set its value as first dropdown value. I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` to get the option with higher values like:

```js
$("#children").change(function() {
  var val = +$(this).val();

  $("#child_going_school option").removeAttr('disabled').filter(function(){
    return +this.value > val;
  }).attr('disabled','disabled')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="children">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="child_going_school">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

Another option is using `hide` and `show` instead of disabling the options.

```js
$("#children").change(function() {
  var val = +$(this).val();
  $("#child_going_school option").show().filter(function() {
    return +this.value > val;
  }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="children">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="child_going_school">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

First get value of first drop down and then compare and disable as below.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#children', function(){
  var fval = $(this).val();
  
  $("#child_going_school option").each(function() {
    var $thisOption = $(this);

    if( $thisOption.val() > parseInt(fval)) {
        $thisOption.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="children">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="child_going_school">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through `child_going_school` options, trigger the change event once loaded and check with the value of `children` select:

```js
$('#children').on('change', function() {
  var value= this.value;
  $('#child_going_school option').each(function(_, el) {
    $(el).prop('disabled', parseInt(value) < parseInt(el.value));
  });
});

$('#children').trigger('change');
```

```js
$('#children').on('change', function() {
  var value = this.value;
  $('#child_going_school option').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', parseInt(value) < parseInt(this.value));
  });
});

$('#children').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="children">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="child_going_school">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#children').change(function(event){
   $('#child_going_school').children().each(function(_, el) {
    $(el).prop('disabled', Number($(el).val()) > event.target.value);
  });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: In this first dropdown change method we can check the selected option with second dropdown options values .
if second dropdown options value  is greater than selected value then that option should be disabled otherwise it should be enabled using event and each method.
By using event we can get the selected value of first dropdown and here children() method is used to get the second dropdown options.